# The use of Seq function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, seq

From the [manual of clojure](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/seq) about `seq` we read: `;; (seq x) is the recommended idiom for testing if a collection is not empty
(every? seq ["1" [1] '(1) {:1 1} #{1}])
;;=> true`. But an empty collection returns itself also `nil`, so what the point of this usage of `seq` for testing emptiness of a collection?

Comment: `(= () nil)   --->  false`

Comment: An empty collection does *not* return `nil`. You are probably thinking of nil-punning, which works in the other direction: if you have `nil` and you are looking for a sequence, it will act as an empty one. *But not vice versa*. In [other lisps](http://clojure.org/lisps), your mileage will vary: *Empty collections are distinct from nil. Clojure does not equate nil and '().*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty collection is not falsey, so in a test it won't matter if it's empty or not:

```
(if '() "a" "b")
=> "a"
```

So if you want to do something else if it's empty:

```
(if (seq '()) "a" "b")
=> "b"
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs at the top of that page:

> seq also works on Strings, native Java arrays (of reference types) and
>   any objects that implement Iterable

So using seq to test emptiness works across any of these collection types. So you get a consistent idiomatic way to check emptiness on any of these types as the example demonstrates.

The fact that seq returns `nil` on both an empty collection and on `nil` makes the check simpler as well, as opposed to needing to check for empty or nil.